# Binding an event on a DOM element to be executed BEFORE an Ajax .load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load, swfupload

I'm coding a website where I use SWFUpload and a lot of Ajax $('#maincontent').load(URL) to replace the content of the main view.

Unfortunately, in IE 7+, when I have an SWFUpload instance in an element from #maincontent and I use .load() to replace the content of #maincontent, I get an infinite loop of errors from SWFUpload that is looking for it's DOM Element (that was removed). (Namely : "unable to set value of the property 'SetFileQueueLimit' : object is null or undefined", "unable to set value of the property 'SetHttpSuccess' : object is null or undefined" indefinitely).

Of course, this more or less blocks the javascript engine and leaves a non-responsive page where no javascript gets fired.

So my question is : how can I bind the Ajax load() of #maincontent so I can do uploader.destroy on my element before it gets removed ?

(Or any other suggestion to fix the IE problem…)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the doc of jquery, the call back of the method load is executed after the content has been changed.
So you might prefer using

```
$.get(URL, function(data) {
  uploader.destroy();
  $('#mainContent').html(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that suggestion may help me for the future. But I have many $('#maincontent').load(URL, callback() {}) in my code, so changing them to your syntax would take some time… but wouldn't solve my problem.

Right now, I have many :

destroyUploader();
$('#maincontent').load('URL', function() {});

Comment: Why taking some time would'nt solve your problem. It's unrelated. By the way, dupplication of code is evil.